# Is it possible to pass extra parameters in moodle webservice function?

Tags: php, web-services, moodle

I am using moodle 3.2. I have added webservice in moodle. With the help of that service I triggered the moodle webservice function in c#. Is it possible to pass extra parameters in moodle webservice function? For example: `function : enrol_manual_enrol_users , input parameters : enrolments[0][roleid]= int,enrolments[0][userid]= int,enrolments[0][courseid]= int,enrolments[0][timestart]= int,enrolments[0][timeend]= int,enrolments[0][suspend]= int.` I have to pass extra one parameter like `enrolments[0][timemodifed]=int`.  Is it possible?